# ng-animate affecting input element, though it shouldn't

Tags: javascript, angularjs, animation

I'm really new with angularjs, and I'm trying to animate only elements I want to animate.

I have injected the ngAnimate module into my app like so:

```
var mrApp = angular.module("mrApp", ["ngRoute", "ngAnimate", "templates"]);
```

This seems to affect every single element in the page that has ng-show or ng-hide, ng-repeat or whatever. Which it should, according to the documentation.

My question is: Am I doing this wrong? Should I have more than one module for my app, to be able to specify which components that should animate? If not, how do I target only specific elements for animation?

EDIT: Something like this? Trying to target elements with classname animate-item. Doesn't seem to work though?

```
var mrApp = angular.module("mrApp", ["ngRoute","ngAnimate","templates"]);

mrApp.config(['$animateProvider', function($animateProvider) {
    $animateProvider.classNameFilter(/animate-item\b/g);
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

From this issue: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/5172

You can use the `$animateProvider.classNameFilter` this way angular will animate only specific classes. You should inject the provider either in your `config` of angular or in the root controller of the application.

EDIT: Here is the documentation for the provider: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/$animateProvider

Basically you should provide a `RegExp`

EDIT: I looked at the code of the `$animateProvider` here: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/animate.js#L5 Take a look at the following code:

```
this.classNameFilter = function(expression) {
    if(arguments.length === 1) {
      this.$$classNameFilter = (expression instanceof RegExp) ? expression : null;
    }
    return this.$$classNameFilter;
  };
```

This means that you should pass your expression as follows:

`$animateProvider.classNameFilter(new RegExp('/animate-item\b/g'));`

Comment: Aaah, ok! I think I understand it now. Will test, and return to accept the answer.